# Django form Inserts record instead of update

Tags: django, django-forms

when i use the id parameter from the url to edit a record, and the "elif 'id' in request.GET:" is being used, it doesn't update the record but it creates a new row

```
@login_required
def login_save_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginSaveForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Create or get login.
            login1 = _login_save(request, form)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(
                                        '/user/%s/' % request.user.username
                                       )
    elif 'id' in request.GET:
     id2 = request.GET['id']
     name=''
     url=''
     Login_username =''
     notes= ''
     password=''
     try:
        login1 = login.objects.get(
                                   id = id2,
                                   username=request.user
                                  )
        name = login1.name
        url = login1.loginUrl
        Login_username = login1.login_username
        notes = login1.notes
        password = login1.password
     except (login.DoesNotExist):
      pass
     form = LoginSaveForm({
        'id': id2,
        'name': name,
        'url': url,
        'Login_username': Login_username,
        'notes': notes,
        'password': password
     })
    else:
        form = LoginSaveForm()
    variables = RequestContext(request, {
                                   'form': form
                                             })
    return render_to_response('login_save_page.html', variables)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your form is submitting via `POST` thus the elif "get" will never fire when you need it to (when the user submits the form).

You'll need to put that logic inside of the `if request.method == 'POST'` block.

Think about when that "elif" block will trigger. Only when the request method is not `POST`, which means only on page load.

Comment: if i do that, when i use the id parameter on url i dont get the current field values of the record, and also a new record is generated. this is what i changed, in case i misunderstood you http://pastebin.com/fZ2ZL7Kp

Comment: Ah, well there's two parts to this puzzle. One is that the get() block needs to populate the records in GET, and during POST it also needs to pull the record and do a different save() action. I might just suggest you use a `ModelForm` where it can differentiate between an update and insert by passing it an instance to modify (or not).